# add to cart using javascript without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am creating an shopping page in which I have many Items that are displayed dinamically from database. I want to be able to add
product in cart without refreshing the page,
I want to know how to submit in javascript and be able to get that expecific data-id.

Normally I would just create a a href and pass product_id as a variable in the URL and then use php to manipulate the variable

```
<?php
$all_products = all_products();
echo '<div class="products">';
      foreach($all_products as $key => $data){

          echo '<div class="single-product">
                      <img src="'.$data['src'].'">
                      <h3>'.$data['name'].'</h3>
                      <h4>'.$data['price'].'</h4>
                      <button type="submit" class="addToCart" data-id="'.$data['product_id'].'">Add to cart</button>
                </div>
          
          ';

     }
 
echo '</div>';
?>

<script>
    let addToCart = document.getElementsByClassName('addToCart');
    addToCart.addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
        //let id = e.querySelector(data-id);
    })

</script>
```

UPDATE

Thank you @M.Eriksson  for your sugestion, I found online this, so if I replace the button with a href and pass javascript function add_to_cart() with product_id inside the variable I can access that variable in javascript using console.log, and I can get the id dinamically, however, I need to manipulate the id and send it using xmlhttpRequest, but it is giving status = 0, I dont see any mistakes in the sintax, and I used the same xmlhttpRequest in other page to request products from server and works

```
<?php
$all_products = all_products();
echo '<div class="products">';
      foreach($all_products as $key => $data){

          echo '<div class="single-product">
                      <img src="'.$data['src'].'">
                      <h3>'.$data['name'].'</h3>
                      <h4>'.$data['price'].'</h4>

                      <a ref="javascript:add_to_cart('.$data['product_id'].')">Add to cart</a>
                </div>
          
          ';

     }
 
echo '</div>';
?>

<script>
    
add_to_cart();

function add_to_cart(product_id=1){
  console.log(product_id);
     let form_data = new FormData();
     form_data.append('product_id', product_id);
     
     let url_data ="php/add_to_cart.php";
     let ajax_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
     ajax_request.open('POST',  url_data);
    let status1 = ajax_request.status;  
    console.log(status1);
    ajax_request.onload = function(){
        //console.log(ajax_request.responseText);
        
        if(status1 == 200){
                let output = JSON.parse(this.response);
                
                //display product added sucessfully
            let added_successfully = document.getElementById('added_successfully');
            added_successfully.innerHTML=output['success'] ;
        }
    }
    ajax_request.send(form_data);

 

}

</script>
```

Comment: you may start by searching for *"how to prevent forms from submitting"* and  *"posting forms using ajax"*. Google is your friend!

Comment: What you're looking for is called Ajax. That allows you to make requests to the server in the background, using JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

what i would do is to change the button type to `button` aka: `<button type="button">Button</button>`

And after that change the EventListener to click and get the target from the event to access the data.

after which you can call a php script from javascript by using the `fetch` function which will send a HTTP request to your backend server.

eg: (untested)

```
<button type="button" class="addToCart" data-id="some data">Add to cart</button>
<script>
    let buttonsList = document.getElementsByClassName('addToCart');
    for (button of buttonsList) {
        button.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
            fetch('/path/to/your/product/api?product_id=' + e.target.getAttribute('data-id')).then((data) => {
                 console.log('product added to cart!')
            })
        })
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: @M.Eriksson you're right, i might have been a little fast on this one, i will modify my answer